# Create a table for data input like in access/excel grid in html to be inserted into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, datagrid

I'm looking to create a table in html to be used to insert the track listing for a CD album. This is not pull info out of the database but rather to insert new data.

I don't want to put one by one with a single form  but rather do all for that album at once

Something like this

[image]

How can this be done with HTML and php to be inserted into a mysql db

I understand this can be done if I put the info into an excel file and upload it to the serever but I want it to be done right on the server

Comment: Please rethink your tags, this has nothing to do with either MS Access or Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after banging my head around I have discovered what I was after was a CRUD Datagrid.

I have gone with the jqery east ui grid as it the exact thing for my use

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php

This grid is pretty simple to use and all the demo files are available from jquery wich makes it even better.

A Thanks to PEM for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommand looking at Dojo Toolkit DataGrid or dgrid, with stores (jsonRest stores or itemFileWriteStore) for the php side, you'd just have to do a fromJson (json_decode) in your controller, then populate some model object (or directly put the info into db after some cleaning to avoid sql injections).